# OpenGL C++ rotating objects around the center of scene

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm making the fish in aquarium and I want to rotate the "walls" and bottom of aquarium around the center of aquarium with dragging the mouse. Except that the scene a bit rotated to be "isometric". The walls just flying like they want (around center, but affecting the shape and position of walls causing them to separate). Here is how it looks[The bug on rotating aquarium walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRXuG.gif). 
The painting function in main class (extending the QGLWidget) is:

```
void OpenGLWidget::paintGL(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glLoadIdentity();
//Draw fish
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(fish.center_x,fish.center_y,fish.center_z);
glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f); // Rotation of 20 degrees around X axis to make scene isometric
glRotatef(camera_y_rotation/32,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f); // Rotates around the Y axis width dragging the left mouse button
glTranslatef(-fish.center_x,-fish.center_y,-fish.center_z);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexGenf(GL_S,GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
glTexGenf(GL_T,GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,fish_texture);
fish.draw();
glPopMatrix();

glLoadIdentity();
//Draw Bottom of Aquarium
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(bottom.center_x,bottom.center_y,bottom.center_z);
glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                //Just like 
glRotatef(camera_y_rotation/32,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f); // with fish
glTranslated(-bottom.center_x,-bottom.center_y,-bottom.center_z);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glTexGenf(GL_S,GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,GL_SPHERE_MAP);
glTexGenf(GL_T,GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE,GL_SPHERE_MAP);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,bottom_texture);
bottom.draw();
glPopMatrix();

glLoadIdentity();
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(water_side.center_x,water_side.center_y,water_side.center_z);
glRotatef(20.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);                //Same here
glRotatef(camera_y_rotation/32,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f); //
glTranslated(-(water_side.center_x),-(water_side.center_y),-(water_side.center_z));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,water_side_texture);
water_side.draw();
glPopMatrix();

swapBuffers();
```

Mouse dragging functions:

```
void OpenGLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton){
    leftMousePressed=true;
    left_mouse_press_position_x=event->x();
    left_mouse_press_position_y=event->y();
}
}
void OpenGLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
if (event->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
    leftMousePressed=false;

}

void OpenGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    GLfloat delta_y=event->x()-left_mouse_press_position_x;
    GLfloat delta_x=event->y()-left_mouse_press_position_y;
    GLfloat rotation_x=camera_x_rotation+delta_x, rotation_y=camera_y_rotation+delta_y;
    if (leftMousePressed){
        if (camera_x_rotation!=rotation_x)
            camera_x_rotation=rotation_x;
        if (camera_y_rotation!=rotation_y)
            camera_y_rotation=rotation_y;
        updateGL();
    }
}
```

Walls of Aquarium header:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <FreeImage.h>
#include <iostream>

class WaterSide
{
public:
    WaterSide();
    void draw();
    GLuint load_texture(FIBITMAP * bitmap);
public:
    double center_x=0.0, center_y=-4.5, center_z=-11;
};
```

Walls of aquarium  draw function:

```
void WaterSide::draw(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3d(-9.0,-9.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,-9.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,0.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(-9.0, 0.0,-2.0);

    glVertex3d(-9.0,-9.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(-9.0,-9.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(-9.0,0.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(-9.0, 0.0,-2.0);

    glVertex3d(-9.0,-9.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,-9.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,0.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(-9.0, 0.0,-20.0);

    glVertex3d(9.0,-9.0,-20.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,-9.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0,0.0,-2.0);
    glVertex3d(9.0, 0.0,-20.0);
    glEnd();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are rotating things over a different center: fish, bottom and water. If your 'draw' commands affect all objects, weird things happen. On a side note, take a look at https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Object_Mouse_Trackball about rotating with the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, your walls are being clipped. 
It looks like opengl has the far and near clipping planes set just behind and just before your walls, which normally would be fine, but when you rotate, the corners *poke through* the clipping planes, and get clipped.

I didn't run your code so i cannot really tell (it's midnight here).

Good luck

Comment: David van rijn, you are right. The walls were just clipped by scene (I thought  they were rotating aroun their own centers or around some other axis). Thank you!

Comment: Nice that it helped, can you maybe accept the answer? For closure, and those sweet points.